# Xpath using get the Attribute value

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I have mentioned the same XML in below .

XML :1

```
 <PP XML="2000_4_174.xml">
      <P name="Antony" value="IN"/>
      <P name="sitting" value="17 AUGUST 2000"/>
      <P name="type" value="reported"/>
      <P name="startpage" value="174"/>
      </PP>
```

XML :2

```
 <PP XML="2000_4_17411.xml">
  <P name="Antony" value="IN"/>
  <P name="sitting" value="17 AUGUST 2000"/>
  <P name="type" value="reported"/>
  <P name="startpage" value="1"/>
  </PP>
```

I have using different condition of in Xpath query for getting @XML value condition(**@name ="Antony" and @value="IN" and @name ="startpage" and @value="174"**) **so expect output is (2000_4_174.xml)**

I have tried this Query please suggest me how to add the another two conditions.

```
let $uri :=  //PP/P[@name="Antony" and @value="IN"] 
for  $i in $uri
let $j := xdmp:node-uri($i)
let $s :=doc($j)/PP/@XML
return $s
```

Comment: I don't get where you're stuck. Is the output wrong, do you get any error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath for that would be :

```
//PP[P[@name="Antony" and @value="IN"] 
         and 
     P[@name="startpage" and @value="174"]
    ]/@XML
```

The XPath should return `XML` attribute of `<PP>` element which contains the following child elements :

```
<P name="Antony" value="IN"/>
<P name="startpage" value="174"/>
```